# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in pdo

Tags: php, pdo

I'm new to pdo just tried the following and getting fatal error.

```
$pdo = new pdo('mysql:localhost;widget_corp;charset=utf-8', 'root', '');
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM 'users'");
$result_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: does pdo have to be uppercase?

Comment: `host=localhost;dbname=widget_corp` just added this and worked. Want to know the reason.

Comment: Actually, there are several issues: 1. `dbname=` in the DSN 2. check for failed queries and display the error using [`errorCode`](http://se2.php.net/manual/de/pdo.errorcode.php) and you should not use apostrophe `'` but rather the backticks `

Comment: This should be put into an SQL debugging book somewhere on planet Earth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
mysql:localhost;widet_corp
```

to

```
mysql:host=localhost;dbname=widget_corp
```

Also in your posted code:

```
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM 'users'");
```

you have the table name inside single quotes. In Mysql you should use a backtick instead for tables and columns.

```
    $query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
```

Comment: `host=localhost;dbname=widget_corp` just added this and worked. Want to know the reason.

Comment: @YousufIqbal Your connection string needs to contain certain information, for mysql, that happens to be the syntax. Not sure what else I can say :)

Answer (score 4):

`PDO::query` return `false` if your query is wrong.

`SELECT * FROM 'users'`

should be

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
```

Comment: `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` will show you the content of the array.

Answer (score 3):

`$pdo->query()` will return false if the query fails. You're not initiating the pdo correctly, and you probably want to check if the query didn't return an error, so:

```
$pdo = new pdo('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=widget_corp;charset=utf-8', 'root', '');
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
if($query !== false)
{
    $result_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: `host=localhost;dbname=widget_corp` this was the error. I wasn't initializing pdo properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=widget_corp;charset=UTF-8', 'root', '');
$query = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
$result_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

If this doesn't work, are you sure that `PDO` is installed properly?

Comment: @YousufIqbal Oh sorry didn't pick up that error. I edited my answer, take a look.