# fetchAll a non object

Tags: pdo

i have the fetchAll a non object error with this code :

```
var_dump($_POST);

include('config_path.php');
$bdd->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE nom_uti_admin= :username AND mdp_admin=:password");
$result = $req->execute(array(
    'username' => $_POST['username'],
    'password' => $_POST['password']
));
$connect = $result->fetchAll();
```

the var_dump return the right value of the last page form...
Do you have any idea of the error ?
The request works well with true value in phpmyadmin !

Thanks

EDIT :

the following code verification :

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    if(count($connect) == 1){
        $_SESSION['auth'] = $cle;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        header("Location: admin/afficher_spec.php");
    }else if(count($connect) == 0){
        echo 'nom d\'utilisateur et/ou mot de passe incorrect !';
    }
}else {
    echo 'Veuillez remplir tous les champs ';
}
```

Comment: Are you using a while or foreach loop?

Comment: hmm... try `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: same, doesn't works :/

Comment: Also please add your loop code

Comment: oh yeah , no is not a foreach, i only test if the returned $connect contain something or not

Comment: You are using a fetchAll so it will return an array started with a [0]. You need to use a loop. While(), foreach() otherwise you can not get the value out. or you have to hardcode $connect[0]['nom_uti_admin'] but that i do not recommend!

Comment: also check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316185/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetchall-on-a-non-object-in-pdo

Comment: If you are using it in a loop use `fetchAll` else use `fetch`

Answer (score 0):

You only use `fetchAll` if you want to loop through it using a foreach loop. In your case you only need to return a single record so you need to use `fetch`

```
$connect = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
if(count($connect) == 1){$_SESSION['auth'] = $cle;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        header("Location: admin/afficher_spec.php");
    }else if(count($connect) != 1){
        echo 'nom d\'utilisateur et/ou mot de passe incorrect !';
    }
```